# How to use progress bar while loading documents from firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrive document from firestore. How do I add a progress bar while the document is loading?
here's my code:

```
documentreference.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                            String UserId=documentSnapshot.getId();

                            ProductModel productModel1 = documentSnapshot.toObject(ProductModel.class).withId(UserId);
                            productModels.add(productModel1);
                            chatListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();




                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Why do you want to add a progress bar for this type of operation? Getting document snapshot is almost instant operation. If you wanted to make a progress bar for upload task, you could add onProgressListener to update the progressbar.
If you still want to add progress bar, for the user experience you can start animation on it after the operation is complete with ObjectAnimator

Answer (score 1):

Show the `ProgressBar` at the start of the activity i.e. just define a `ProgressBar` in xml and make sure its visible in the start.

Now, when all your data is loaded, just make it gone.

```js
documentreference.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener < DocumentSnapshot > () {
  @Override
  public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
    String UserId = documentSnapshot.getId();

    ProductModel productModel1 = documentSnapshot.toObject(ProductModel.class).withId(UserId);
    productModels.add(productModel1);
    chatListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    progressBar.setVisibilty(View.GONE);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
documentreference.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener < DocumentSnapshot > () {
  @Override
  public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
    String UserId = documentSnapshot.getId();

    ProductModel productModel1 = documentSnapshot.toObject(ProductModel.class).withId(UserId);
    productModels.add(productModel1);
    chatListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    progressBar.setVisibilty(View.GONE);
  }
});
```